# How to disable keyboard?

Tags: linux, keyboard, kernel-modules

Without unplugging my keyboard I'd like to disable it from the terminal; I was hoping that this could be done using `rmmod` but based on my currently loaded modules it doesn't look like it is possible.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The HID ("human interface device") module is probably built-in.  Some of the USB stuff may not be tho, so you could try pulling one of those (`lsmod | grep usb`).

Comment: Hmmm: http://wpkg.org/Disable_/_enable_keyboard_and_mouse_in_Linux

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are pretty good directions on doing it here, titled: [Disable / enable keyboard and mouse in Linux](http://wpkg.org/Disable_/_enable_keyboard_and_mouse_in_Linux).

#### Example

You can list the devices with this command.

```
$ xinput --list
"Virtual core pointer"  id=0    [XPointer]
"Virtual core keyboard" id=1    [XKeyboard]
"Keyboard2"     id=2    [XExtensionKeyboard]
"Mouse2"        id=3    [XExtensionKeyboard]
```

And disable the keyboard with this:

```
$ xinput set-int-prop 2 "Device Enabled" 8 0
```

And enable it with this one:

```
$ xinput set-int-prop 2 "Device Enabled" 8 1
```

This only works for disabling the keyboard through X. So if you're on a system that isn't running X this won't work.

#### List of properties

You can use this command to get a list of all the properties for a given device:

```
$ xinput --list-props 2
Device 'Virtual core keyboard':
    Device Enabled (124):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (126): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
```

Comment: Will it be reactivated if unplugged and plugged back in? Might be tricky to get a response from the machine (unless it's a laptop) otherwise :)

Comment: Yeah these disable device questions always seem loaded for the "ok so how do I re-enable it" piece.

Comment: I would add that this disables the keyboard only for X11 and not for any TTY. Also you can still switch to the TTYs with Ctrl+Alt+F?

Comment: @RaphaelAhrens - yeah I said that in the answer, but thanks for re-iterating it.

Comment: @terdon Make sure you have a working SSH connection before experimenting.

Comment: Can we not use `xinput float <id>` and `xinput reattach <id> <master>`? Is it any different?
It feels intuitive though.

Comment: @reza.safiyat - if you have a new question, please ask it. You can reference this Q with yours being a follow-up or asking for more refinement.

Comment: Not a new question, no. But just another method to do action.
Is it any different?