# Disable the external keyboard from a script

Tags: linux, x11, keyboard, udev, xinput

I have a udev rule for my external keyboard. I can catch events, and by running a script I can also reach udev env variables. Can I disable keyboard with udev? Or must I use a script to disable the keyboard in another way.

There is a one way to disable keyboard with script to running `xinput` but it wants an "id". How can I get the id information for `xinput` from udev? or is there another effective way?

Whole trace when I monitor udev for keyboard:

```
KERNEL[2563.037091] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2 (usb)
ACTION=add
BUSNUM=002
DEVICE=/proc/bus/usb/002/003
DEVNAME=bus/usb/002/003
DEVNUM=003
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2
DEVTYPE=usb_device
MAJOR=189
MINOR=130
PRODUCT=1c4f/2/110
SEQNUM=1538
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0
UDEV_LOG=3

KERNEL[2563.037837] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0 (usb)
ACTION=add
DEVICE=/proc/bus/usb/002/003
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
INTERFACE=3/1/1
MODALIAS=usb:v1C4Fp0002d0110dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc01ip01
PRODUCT=1c4f/2/110
SEQNUM=1539
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0
UDEV_LOG=3

KERNEL[2563.038023] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/0003:1C4F:0002.0005 (hid)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/0003:1C4F:0002.0005
HID_ID=0003:00001C4F:00000002
HID_NAME=SIGMACH1P USB Keykoard
HID_PHYS=usb-0000:09:00.0-2/input0
MODALIAS=hid:b0003v00001C4Fp00000002
SEQNUM=1540
SUBSYSTEM=hid
UDEV_LOG=3

KERNEL[2563.040754] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/input/input17 (input)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/input/input17
EV=120013
KEY=1000000000007 ff800000000007ff febeffdff3cfffff fffffffffffffffe
LED=7
MODALIAS=input:b0003v1C4Fp0002e0110-e0,1,4,11,14,k71,72,73,74,75,77,79,7A,7B,7C,7D,7E,7F,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,8A,B7,B8,B9,BA,BB,BC,BD,BE,BF,C0,C1,C2,F0,ram4,l0,1,2,sfw
MSC=10
NAME="SIGMACH1P USB Keykoard"
PHYS="usb-0000:09:00.0-2/input0"
PRODUCT=3/1c4f/2/110
PROP=0
SEQNUM=1541
SUBSYSTEM=input
UDEV_LOG=3
UNIQ=""

KERNEL[2563.040970] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/input/input17/event6 (input)
ACTION=add
DEVNAME=input/event6
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/input/input17/event6
MAJOR=13
MINOR=70
SEQNUM=1542
SUBSYSTEM=input
UDEV_LOG=3

KERNEL[2563.041090] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/0003:1C4F:0002.0005/hidraw/hidraw2 (hidraw)
ACTION=add
DEVNAME=hidraw2
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/0003:1C4F:0002.0005/hidraw/hidraw2
MAJOR=252
MINOR=2
SEQNUM=1543
SUBSYSTEM=hidraw
UDEV_LOG=3

KERNEL[2563.041168] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.1 (usb)
ACTION=add
DEVICE=/proc/bus/usb/002/003
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.1
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
INTERFACE=3/0/0
MODALIAS=usb:v1C4Fp0002d0110dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc00ip00
PRODUCT=1c4f/2/110
SEQNUM=1544
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0
UDEV_LOG=3

KERNEL[2563.041309] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.1/0003:1C4F:0002.0006 (hid)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.1/0003:1C4F:0002.0006
HID_ID=0003:00001C4F:00000002
HID_NAME=SIGMACH1P USB Keykoard
HID_PHYS=usb-0000:09:00.0-2/input1
MODALIAS=hid:b0003v00001C4Fp00000002
SEQNUM=1545
SUBSYSTEM=hid
UDEV_LOG=3

KERNEL[2563.044144] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.1/input/input18 (input)
ABS=100000000
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.1/input/input18
EV=1f
KEY=4837fff072ff32d bf54444600000000 1 20c100b17c000 267bfad941dfed 9e168000004400 10000002
MODALIAS=input:b0003v1C4Fp0002e0110-e0,1,2,3,4,k71,72,73,74,77,80,82,83,85,86,87,88,89,8A,8B,8C,8E,8F,90,96,98,9B,9C,9E,9F,A1,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9,AB,AC,AD,AE,B1,B2,B5,CE,CF,D0,D1,D2,D4,D8,D9,DB,E4,EA,EB,F1,100,161,162,166,16A,16E,172,174,176,178,179,17A,17B,17C,17D,17F,180,182,183,185,188,189,18C,18D,18E,18F,190,191,192,193,195,198,199,19A,1A0,1A1,1A2,1A3,1A4,1A5,1A6,1A7,1A8,1A9,1AA,1AB,1AC,1AD,1AE,1B0,1B1,1B7,1BA,r6,a20,m4,lsfw
MSC=10
NAME="SIGMACH1P USB Keykoard"
PHYS="usb-0000:09:00.0-2/input1"
PRODUCT=3/1c4f/2/110
PROP=0
REL=40
SEQNUM=1546
SUBSYSTEM=input
UDEV_LOG=3
UNIQ=""

KERNEL[2563.044365] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.1/input/input18/event7 (input)
ACTION=add
DEVNAME=input/event7
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.1/input/input18/event7
MAJOR=13
MINOR=71
SEQNUM=1547
SUBSYSTEM=input
UDEV_LOG=3

KERNEL[2563.044560] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.1/0003:1C4F:0002.0006/hidraw/hidraw3 (hidraw)
ACTION=add
DEVNAME=hidraw3
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.1/0003:1C4F:0002.0006/hidraw/hidraw3
MAJOR=252
MINOR=3
SEQNUM=1548
SUBSYSTEM=hidraw
UDEV_LOG=3

UDEV  [2563.066401] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2 (usb)
ACTION=add
BUSNUM=002
DEVICE=/proc/bus/usb/002/003
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/002/003
DEVNUM=003
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2
DEVTYPE=usb_device
ID_BUS=usb
ID_MODEL=USB_Keykoard
ID_MODEL_ENC=USB\x20Keykoard
ID_MODEL_ID=0002
ID_REVISION=0110
ID_SERIAL=SIGMACH1P_USB_Keykoard
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030101:030000:
ID_VENDOR=SIGMACH1P
ID_VENDOR_ENC=SIGMACH1P
ID_VENDOR_ID=1c4f
MAJOR=189
MINOR=130
PRODUCT=1c4f/2/110
SEQNUM=1538
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0
UDEV_LOG=3
USEC_INITIALIZED=2563048257

UDEV  [2563.071837] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.1 (usb)
ACTION=add
DEVICE=/proc/bus/usb/002/003
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.1
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
INTERFACE=3/0/0
MODALIAS=usb:v1C4Fp0002d0110dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc00ip00
PRODUCT=1c4f/2/110
SEQNUM=1544
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0
UDEV_LOG=3
USEC_INITIALIZED=2563068334

UDEV  [2563.072377] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0 (usb)
ACTION=add
DEVICE=/proc/bus/usb/002/003
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
INTERFACE=3/1/1
MODALIAS=usb:v1C4Fp0002d0110dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc01ip01
PRODUCT=1c4f/2/110
SEQNUM=1539
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0
UDEV_LOG=3
USEC_INITIALIZED=2563068933

UDEV  [2563.079363] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/0003:1C4F:0002.0005 (hid)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/0003:1C4F:0002.0005
HID_ID=0003:00001C4F:00000002
HID_NAME=SIGMACH1P USB Keykoard
HID_PHYS=usb-0000:09:00.0-2/input0
MODALIAS=hid:b0003v00001C4Fp00000002
SEQNUM=1540
SUBSYSTEM=hid
UDEV_LOG=3
USEC_INITIALIZED=2563074770

UDEV  [2563.080760] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/0003:1C4F:0002.0005/hidraw/hidraw2 (hidraw)
ACTION=add
DEVNAME=/dev/hidraw2
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/0003:1C4F:0002.0005/hidraw/hidraw2
MAJOR=252
MINOR=2
SEQNUM=1543
SUBSYSTEM=hidraw
UDEV_LOG=3
USEC_INITIALIZED=2563080427

UDEV  [2563.084307] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.1/0003:1C4F:0002.0006 (hid)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.1/0003:1C4F:0002.0006
HID_ID=0003:00001C4F:00000002
HID_NAME=SIGMACH1P USB Keykoard
HID_PHYS=usb-0000:09:00.0-2/input1
MODALIAS=hid:b0003v00001C4Fp00000002
SEQNUM=1545
SUBSYSTEM=hid
UDEV_LOG=3
USEC_INITIALIZED=2563073436

UDEV  [2563.085738] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.1/0003:1C4F:0002.0006/hidraw/hidraw3 (hidraw)
ACTION=add
DEVNAME=/dev/hidraw3
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.1/0003:1C4F:0002.0006/hidraw/hidraw3
MAJOR=252
MINOR=3
SEQNUM=1548
SUBSYSTEM=hidraw
UDEV_LOG=3
USEC_INITIALIZED=2563085486

UDEV  [2563.238882] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.1/input/input18 (input)
ABS=100000000
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.1/input/input18
EV=1f
ID_BUS=usb
ID_INPUT=1
ID_INPUT_KEY=1
ID_MODEL=USB_Keykoard
ID_MODEL_ENC=USB\x20Keykoard
ID_MODEL_ID=0002
ID_PATH=pci-0000:09:00.0-usb-0:2:1.1
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_09_00_0-usb-0_2_1_1
ID_REVISION=0110
ID_SERIAL=SIGMACH1P_USB_Keykoard
ID_TYPE=hid
ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030101:030000:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=01
ID_VENDOR=SIGMACH1P
ID_VENDOR_ENC=SIGMACH1P
ID_VENDOR_ID=1c4f
KEY=4837fff072ff32d bf54444600000000 1 20c100b17c000 267bfad941dfed 9e168000004400 10000002
MODALIAS=input:b0003v1C4Fp0002e0110-e0,1,2,3,4,k71,72,73,74,77,80,82,83,85,86,87,88,89,8A,8B,8C,8E,8F,90,96,98,9B,9C,9E,9F,A1,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9,AB,AC,AD,AE,B1,B2,B5,CE,CF,D0,D1,D2,D4,D8,D9,DB,E4,EA,EB,F1,100,161,162,166,16A,16E,172,174,176,178,179,17A,17B,17C,17D,17F,180,182,183,185,188,189,18C,18D,18E,18F,190,191,192,193,195,198,199,19A,1A0,1A1,1A2,1A3,1A4,1A5,1A6,1A7,1A8,1A9,1AA,1AB,1AC,1AD,1AE,1B0,1B1,1B7,1BA,r6,a20,m4,lsfw
MSC=10
NAME="SIGMACH1P USB Keykoard"
PHYS="usb-0000:09:00.0-2/input1"
PRODUCT=3/1c4f/2/110
PROP=0
REL=40
SEQNUM=1546
SUBSYSTEM=input
UDEV_LOG=3
UNIQ=""
USEC_INITIALIZED=2563044149

UDEV  [2563.391000] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/input/input17 (input)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/input/input17
EV=120013
ID_BUS=usb
ID_INPUT=1
ID_INPUT_KEY=1
ID_INPUT_KEYBOARD=1
ID_MODEL=USB_Keykoard
ID_MODEL_ENC=USB\x20Keykoard
ID_MODEL_ID=0002
ID_PATH=pci-0000:09:00.0-usb-0:2:1.0
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_09_00_0-usb-0_2_1_0
ID_REVISION=0110
ID_SERIAL=SIGMACH1P_USB_Keykoard
ID_TYPE=hid
ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030101:030000:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
ID_VENDOR=SIGMACH1P
ID_VENDOR_ENC=SIGMACH1P
ID_VENDOR_ID=1c4f
KEY=1000000000007 ff800000000007ff febeffdff3cfffff fffffffffffffffe
LED=7
MODALIAS=input:b0003v1C4Fp0002e0110-e0,1,4,11,14,k71,72,73,74,75,77,79,7A,7B,7C,7D,7E,7F,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,8A,B7,B8,B9,BA,BB,BC,BD,BE,BF,C0,C1,C2,F0,ram4,l0,1,2,sfw
MSC=10
NAME="SIGMACH1P USB Keykoard"
PHYS="usb-0000:09:00.0-2/input0"
PRODUCT=3/1c4f/2/110
PROP=0
SEQNUM=1541
SUBSYSTEM=input
UDEV_LOG=3
UNIQ=""
USEC_INITIALIZED=2563040766

UDEV  [2563.410790] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.1/input/input18/event7 (input)
ACTION=add
BACKSPACE=guess
DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-id/usb-SIGMACH1P_USB_Keykoard-event-if01 /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:09:00.0-usb-0:2:1.1-event
DEVNAME=/dev/input/event7
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.1/input/input18/event7
ID_BUS=usb
ID_INPUT=1
ID_INPUT_KEY=1
ID_MODEL=USB_Keykoard
ID_MODEL_ENC=USB\x20Keykoard
ID_MODEL_ID=0002
ID_PATH=pci-0000:09:00.0-usb-0:2:1.1
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_09_00_0-usb-0_2_1_1
ID_REVISION=0110
ID_SERIAL=SIGMACH1P_USB_Keykoard
ID_TYPE=hid
ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030101:030000:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=01
ID_VENDOR=SIGMACH1P
ID_VENDOR_ENC=SIGMACH1P
ID_VENDOR_ID=1c4f
MAJOR=13
MINOR=71
SEQNUM=1547
SUBSYSTEM=input
UDEV_LOG=3
USEC_INITIALIZED=2563239989
XKBLAYOUT=tr
XKBMODEL=pc105
XKBOPTIONS=lv3:ralt_switch

UDEV  [2563.576817] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/input/input17/event6 (input)
ACTION=add
BACKSPACE=guess
DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-id/usb-SIGMACH1P_USB_Keykoard-event-kbd /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:09:00.0-usb-0:2:1.0-event-kbd
DEVNAME=/dev/input/event6
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:09:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/input/input17/event6
ID_BUS=usb
ID_INPUT=1
ID_INPUT_KEY=1
ID_INPUT_KEYBOARD=1
ID_MODEL=USB_Keykoard
ID_MODEL_ENC=USB\x20Keykoard
ID_MODEL_ID=0002
ID_PATH=pci-0000:09:00.0-usb-0:2:1.0
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_09_00_0-usb-0_2_1_0
ID_REVISION=0110
ID_SERIAL=SIGMACH1P_USB_Keykoard
ID_TYPE=hid
ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030101:030000:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
ID_VENDOR=SIGMACH1P
ID_VENDOR_ENC=SIGMACH1P
ID_VENDOR_ID=1c4f
MAJOR=13
MINOR=70
SEQNUM=1542
SUBSYSTEM=input
UDEV_LOG=3
USEC_INITIALIZED=2563392826
XKBLAYOUT=tr
XKBMODEL=pc105
XKBOPTIONS=lv3:ralt_switch
```

EDIT FOR SHW POST

System info

Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.2 (wheezy)
Release:    7.2
Codename:   wheezy

udev version 175

Unbind keyboard syslog result

```
Jan 16 13:47:50  acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 13
Jan 16 13:47:51  kernel: [  694.216123] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 17
Jan 16 13:47:51  acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 15
Jan 16 13:47:51  kernel: [  694.507848] usb 1-1.3: new low-speed USB device number 18 using ehci_hcd
Jan 16 13:47:51  kernel: [  694.606225] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=1c4f, idProduct=0002
Jan 16 13:47:51  kernel: [  694.606235] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jan 16 13:47:51  kernel: [  694.606242] usb 1-1.3: Product: USB Keykoard
Jan 16 13:47:51  kernel: [  694.606246] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: SIGMACH1P
Jan 16 13:47:51  kernel: [  694.609792] input: SIGMACH1P USB Keykoard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/input/input57
Jan 16 13:47:51  kernel: [  694.610190] generic-usb 0003:1C4F:0002.0027: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [SIGMACH1P USB Keykoard] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.3/input0
Jan 16 13:47:51  kernel: [  694.613248] input: SIGMACH1P USB Keykoard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.1/input/input58
Jan 16 13:47:51  kernel: [  694.613646] generic-usb 0003:1C4F:0002.0028: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Device [SIGMACH1P USB Keykoard] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.3/input1
Jan 16 13:47:51  mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 18: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3"
Jan 16 13:47:51  mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 18 was not an MTP device
```

Comment: Could you explain what you want a bit more? You simply want your external keyboard to be ignored? Why don't you simply leave it unplugged?

Comment: unfortunately customer requirement. they want to manage keyboards.

Comment: They want to be able to manually switch between connected keyboards? How would you do this through `udev`? It only detects when devices are plugged in/out. When exactly do you want the device to be disabled? Do you simply want it to be always ignored?

Comment: they want to disable or enable keyboard dynamically. i am using udev for detect the device. i can get all information of device when plug or unplug via udev. i am searching alternative way to disable/enable keyboard dynamically. obviously, scenario - when user plug a externall keyboard i am looking user permission and if he has not permission i am disabling the keyboard if he has enabling.

Answer (score 3):

#### Using a script

One method would be via a script that gets invoked as a script from UDEV. The method I would take, I fleshed out in this U&L Q&A titled: [How to disable keyboard?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91075/how-to-disable-keyboard/91078#91078).

There are pretty good directions on enabling/disabling a keyboard here as well, titled: [Disable / enable keyboard and mouse in Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91075/how-to-disable-keyboard/91078#91078).

#### Example

You can list the devices with this command.

```
$ xinput --list
"Virtual core pointer"  id=0    [XPointer]
"Virtual core keyboard" id=1    [XKeyboard]
"Keyboard2"     id=2    [XExtensionKeyboard]
"Mouse2"        id=3    [XExtensionKeyboard]
```

And disable the keyboard with this:

```
$ xinput set-int-prop 2 "Device Enabled" 8 0
```

And enable it with this one:

```
$ xinput set-int-prop 2 "Device Enabled" 8 1
```

So you could put the above commands into scripts that UDEV could call them.

**NOTE:** This only works for disabling the keyboard through X. So if you're on a system that isn't running X this won't work.

#### Using UDEV

I think you might be able to adapt one of these rules to disable a USB based keyboard using a rule similar to this one:

```
BUS=="usb", KERNEL=="hdb", OPTIONS+="ignore_device"
```

You'd need to determine the identifications for your external keyboard. I believe all the information you'd need to craft one of these rules is included in the output that you included in your question.

Comment: thanks for your reply slm. i know we can disable keyboard via xinput but how can i get id information from udev ?

Comment: @ibasaran - you have to go through the output you posted and determine which device is your keyboard. You can then make a corresponding `.rules` file and place it in `/etc/udev/rules.d/`. The key info is the rule needs to have `OPTIONS+="ignore_device"` in it so that UDEV will effectively disable the keyboard device.

Comment: sorry for late reply, ignore_device not working anymore. https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kubuntu-users/2010-November/052927.html

Comment: @ibasaran - can you elaborate please? Not working how?

Comment: http://lwn.net/Articles/364728/ No longer exists "ignore device"

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can disable any USB device, in this case, keyboard.
Navigate to directory `/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbhid`

It will list all the USB HID device's number. 
For your keyboard, find out correct number and execute the command:

`echo -n 2-1.4:1.0 > unbind`

It will unbind (disable) the underlying USB hardware
To enable it again, execute

`echo -n 2-1.4:1.0 > bind`

Here, issue is to find out correct number. But that can be solved by knowing the vendor and product id

Comment: Thnks for your replay SHW. Right, this way disabling my keyboard. But one problem, i unbind my keyboard after few seconds it authomatically binds again.

Comment: IIRC, only UDEV can bind the hardware. By any chance, are you reloading the rules OR restarting the UDEVD ?

Comment: Right when i unbind device, udev binding again but i am not reloadig rules again. it is happing automatically.

Comment: also i unbind a storage. storage not binding again but keyboard binding again.

Comment: I tried at my (custom) distro. It works as expected for USB keyboard. Udev version 197 is here.  Can you post `dmesg` output and/or /var/log/syslog file content ?

Comment: edited orginal post syslog output.

Comment: Just for cross-checking UDEV version, can you exercise this on new LIVE OS ?

Comment: also i checked ubuntu 12.04 udev version. it is 175. i will try to upgrade udev for testing.

Comment: The "rebind again" issue is that udev sees the keyboard and re-binds it.  (Makes for a nice reset for my little project)  It's a feature/misfeature of how it sees input devices.