# How to turn display off and ignore mouse movement?

Tags: ubuntu, x11, display, dpms

I'd like to put the built-in display into standby (E.G. `xset dpms force off`) and keep the display off even if the mouse moves. That is, I want to ignore mouse movement for the purposes of waking the display. How can I achieve this?

The use case is: I'm using Synergy to control other machines, and the built in display on the host generates a lot of heat. if I'm not actively using it, I'd like the display to sleep while focused on another machine.

The accepted answer in [Can I force screen blank and ignore input?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266274/can-i-force-screen-blank-and-ignore-input) doesn't work for me because  I want X11 to be able to receive mouse input, I just don't want that mouse input to wake the screen (I.E. that suggestion causes Synergy to lose access to the mouse input)

Comment: Thanks @StephenKitt I didn't find that one, not sure how... it's the exact same question.

Comment: You’re welcome. I’m not sure it will work with Synergy though :-/.

Comment: @StephenKitt sadly, it doesn't work... then Synergy loses access to the mouse. It may be that what I want to do isn't possible...

Comment: Right, I wondered as much. I’ll flag the question for re-opening.

Comment: (For future commenters and reviewers, the duplicate suggested was [Can I force screen blank and ignore input?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266274/can-i-force-screen-blank-and-ignore-input))

Comment: Thanks @StephenKitt! I edited the question to clarify why it's not an exact duplicate (well, it is, but I want a different answer than the other question)